# The multi-part identifier could not be bound - SET clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I've searched for this answer, but most seem to come from the table being updated rather than the table having the information being taken from.

The first B.DED1 in the SET is the one throwing the multi-part identifier. Yet the one in the WHERE clause works just fine.

```
UPDATE #output
SET col1 = B.DED1
SELECT * 
FROM #output A  
 INNER JOIN TableName B
 ON A.Key = B.Key
WHERE B.DED1 = 'col1'
```

Comment: Please add the table structure of the tables in text format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE A
SET col1 = B.DED1
FROM [#output] A  
 INNER JOIN TableName B
 ON A.Key = B.Key
WHERE B.DED1 = 'col1'
```

Comment: Wow do I feel like an idiot having a SELECT statement in there. Forgot to remove it after testing to make sure the join worked properly. Thank you!

Comment: anytime :) glad to help

Answer (score 2):

Change your query as following:

```
UPDATE O SET col1 = B.DED1
FROM [#output] O  
INNER JOIN TableName B
ON O.Key = B.Key
WHERE B.DED1 = 'col1'
```